# Integrity constraint violation: 1052

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-8

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `kumeti_member_registrations` left join `members list` on `members list`.`id` = `kumeti_member registrations`.`member_name` where `id` = 2)",

this Query please solve the error

```
$result = DB::table('kumeti_member_registrations')
            ->leftjoin('members_list', 'members_list.id', '=', 'kumeti_member_registrations.member_name')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = DB::table('kumeti_member_registrations')
            ->leftjoin('members_list', 'members_list.id', '=', 'kumeti_member_registrations.member_name')
            ->where('kumeti_member_registrations.id', $id)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the table name as `id` is common in both tables and is therefore ambiguous

So

```
->where('kumeti_member_registrations.id', $id)
```

Comment: i think it is not alias error